# How can I insert a variable into an SQL Statement in Razor (cshtml)?

Tags: c#, razor

I am using CSHTML (C#) to access a SQL database. I am not sure why i cannot seem to use the @0 to reference C# variables. Sorry first time posting, tell me if there are any issues with my post

(artistsearch is a string)

// --- WORKING CODE --- //

```
var queryStatement = "SELECT ArtistId "
                    + "FROM Artists "
                    + "WHERE Name  '%" + artistsearch + "%' ";
var queryArtists = db.Query(queryStatement);
```

// --- NOT WORKING CODE --- //

```
var queryStatement = "SELECT ArtistId "
                        + "FROM Artists "
                        + "WHERE Name LIKE @0 ";
var queryArtists = db.Query(queryStatement, artistsearch);
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow, Are you aware of what are you doing?! can I ask why you do this in razor?!